# How do I represent a “none” value in NSUserDefaults?

Tags: cocoa, macos, nsuserdefaults

I am storing [keyboard shortcuts](http://code.google.com/p/shortcutrecorder) represented as `NSDictionary` instances into user defaults and have some trouble representing “none” values. When my application starts I register some default shortcuts. Then the user may change keyboard shortcuts in application preferences. The keyboard setting widgets are bound directly to user defaults.

The user may click a special “clear” button that clears a keyboard shortcut, meaning that user does not wish to set a shorcut for given feature. When the keyboard shortcut is cleared, it’s set to `nil`. This is a problem, because setting the shortcut to `nil` in user defaults reverts the value to the one registered with `registerDefaults:`. (The `objectForKey:` method does not find given key in the app domain and therefore goes into the `NSRegistrationDomain` domain.)

How should I represent the “cleared” keyboard shortcuts so that `objectForKey:` returns `nil`? Do I have to play games with empty `NSDictionary` instances and other sentinel values, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using this transformer:

```
@interface NullTransformer : NSValueTransformer {}
@end

@implementation NullTransformer

+ (BOOL) allowsReverseTransformation {
    return YES;
}

- (id) transformedValue: (id) value {
    return [value count] ? value : nil;
}

- (id) reverseTransformedValue: (id) value {
    return value ? value : [NSDictionary dictionary];
}

@end
```

In other words, I use an empty dictionary to represent unset values and convert between this special value and `nil` using a custom transformer so that my classes don’t have to care. It’s not perfect, but seems like a tolerable solution.